# Excel: output dynamically

Tags: excel

If the value of cell is 6 for example, how to output dynamically as followed in excel:

```
6
A1~A2
A2~A3
A3~A4
A4~A5
A5~A6
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what does A1~A2 mean? And what are you expecting it to output?

Comment: A1, A2 represents axis name(I am a structural engineer). In fact, `A` is just a leading letter. 1~6 is the real axis name. A1~A2 means the area between axis A1 and A2. 6 is the total of all axises.

Comment: Ok, you should put yourself in the readers point of view: I put a 6 or some other number (what range?!) into a cell. Then some other cells shall change accordingly (how many cells? by what rules do they change?!). I am guessing when you would state 8 in some cell, then somewhere else there should be cells filled with "A1~A2" to "A7~A8" - is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I am sorry that my English is not good enough. The number is just a small integer, no larger than 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, then I would suggest you copy this formula for 20 rows, or as many as you need:

```
 =IF(A$1>ROW()+1-ROW(B$1),"A"&ROW()+1-ROW(B$1)&"~A"&ROW()+2-ROW(B$1),"")
```

Then you would get your result, when you set

```
A1 = 6
```

and

```
B1 = IF(A$1>ROW()+1-ROW(B$1),"A"&ROW()+1-ROW(B$1)&"~A"&ROW()+2-ROW(B$1),"")
```

Hope this helps.

*EDIT:*

```
B1 = IF(A$1>ROW()+1-ROW(B$1),"A"&CHAR(ROW()-ROW(B$1)+65)&"~A"&CHAR(ROW()-ROW(B$1)+66),"")
```

Comment: How to change the number to letter? e.g.: AA~AB, AB~AC etc. accordingly. I am a newbie of excel and don't know how to use your formula flexibly.

Comment: my formular got your number based on the distance of the current row to the row of B1. If you need to change that into a letter, use the formula of my edit. By the way, if you are that new to excel, I would suggest you to play around a bit more, use the excel-help and if a formula is complicated, try to divide it into seperate parts, to understand the magic behind.

Comment: Thank you for your "EDIT" and suggestion.